# Maintaining word order when copying Hebrew from and SE site to MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, web, copy-paste, right-to-left, hebrew

When I try to copy text from [Mi Yodeya](http://mi.yodeya.com) (the Judaism SE site, which I usually render in Chrome) into a MS Word document (using Word 2007 on Windows 7), e.g. [this one](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1944/2), I find that Hebrew text comes through with the words in reverse order. Is there a convenient way to make the text end up in the right order? I'm open to techniques in MS Word, techniques in editing the posts in SE, or anything in between.

Per a suggestion from [and31415](https://superuser.com/users/289138/and31415), I followed the procedures in [this link](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/keyboards/winrtl.html) to add a Hebrew keyboard, turn it on, and add the RTL and LTR buttons to Word. The text still pastes in with the words in reverse order, and if I select it and hit the RTL button, the still-reversed sentence just moves over to the right of the page.

Comment: You should specify the operating system you have installed, the browser you're using, and the Microsoft Word version.

Comment: @and31415 Thanks. I added the browser. The other two were already in there.

Comment: Did you try [enabling the right-to-left direction](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/keyboards/winrtl.html) in Word already?

Comment: @and31415 Thanks. I just followed the procedures in your link to add a Hebrew keyboard, turn it on, and add the RTL and LTR buttons to Word. The text still pastes in with the words in reverse order, and if I select it and hit the RTL button, the still-reversed sentence just moves over to the right of the page. I'm adding this information to the quesiton.

Comment: I don't have quite the same combination here (Word2007+Vista+Chrome) but all works OK. I'll try to see what's actually in the clipboard. If you paste into Notepad, then select, re-copy and paste into Word, does that make any difference.

Comment: @bibadia, When I paste into Notepad, the order is correct. When I copy from Notepad and paste into Word, the order is incorrect.

Comment: @Isaac Moses: Still unable to reproduce here. I have sometimes seen partial reversal when copying from IE (probably to do with the way "()" is encoded). Looking at the clipboard here reveals that at least one of the formats that Chrome puts on the clipboard ("OEM Text") is _probably_ reversed, but nothing I do here seems to insert that version. There are some suggestions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9613613/why-words-are-shuffled-when-i-insert-english-words-in-any-arabic-urdu-persian-te which you could try but I suspect there is another factor.

Comment: If you can save a sample as a .docx immediately post-edit and put it somewhere downloadable, I'll have a look at what's actually in the file and see if I can find a way to reverse the sequence.

Comment: @bibadia, Thanks! [Here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0TqzcduQYHTOFVIX3FHeW5ZMUU/edit?usp=sharing) the .docx file. (Nice. When GDocs renders it, it puts the words in the right order. When I download the file and open in Word, I get the wrong order.) I'm contemplating finding/creating a VBA script to re-reverse the words as a possible last resort.

Comment: Not much further, but can we move to superuser's "chat" facility? I have never used it but I believe that's what we are supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a convenient way to make the text end up in the right order?

Yes, change the paragraph direction from Left-to-Right to Right-to-Left, and the word order will be corrected. This works for me with MS Word 2010.

I'm not sure exactly why we see the words in reverse order. I suspected the reason for this weird behavior was embedded Unicode control characters in that text, but that's not the case (To make sure of this claim, copy the text into a text file, take a hex dump of it, and put it in [here](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder) as 'Hexadecimal' to get a UTF-8 analysis.)

Comment: Don't you find that changing the paragraph direction is not enough if, for example, the text contains () as in the sample file? The trouble is that I do not think Word applies the Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm in that case and the text is only partially rearranged. At least, that's what happens here.

Comment: Well, no. (Except that the closing parenthesis is mis-directed even after I change the paragraph direction.)

Comment: Yes, it is just the braces, isn't it.

Comment: Is this different than using the RTL button, as described in the question? I tried that, and it didn't work.

Comment: @IsaacMoses: I'm not exactly sure which buttons the question refers to... if they're the paragraph direction buttons, then yes, and then my answer is "Works for Me (TM)".

Answer (score 0):

Just solved this for myself while reading through the comments.

It must be in the coding.

When I am copying Hebrew text from my browser, if I first paste it into "WordPad" NOT Word Docx, and then copy FROM "WordPad" into Word Docx, it doesn't reverse the letters. Almost like the extra coding is "lost" after posting it to WordPad, probably because its a 'simple' program.

Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: Interesting. Did you try Notepad?

Answer (score -1):

it could be that you didn't download the Hebrew proof reading package from Microsoft.  I had the same problem and when I downloaded it the problem cleared up.

Comment: an answer can not be based on assumptions, and it would be answered based in facts and references